# How to create a texture for icicles

Tags: modeling, texturing

I have some very simple icicles that I made using the icicle generator addon.

[image]

I was wondering how to create a distortion/texture on the icicles to make it look realistic. Here is an example of what I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: With lighting from the first screenshot it's likely pretty much impossible to achieve the same look. Add some environment lighting, add volumetric material to the icicles and it should provide something at least for starting. This will be quite resources heavy way though

Comment: Could you provide link to this add-on? I can make an answer but I need to know if its possible to add some loop cuts to the icicles and UV Maps.

Comment: Here is the link: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331186-Add-On-Snowflake-and-Icicle-generator.  And yes, you can add loop cuts and use UV mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Final:

[image: Final]

### Node setup:

[image: nodes]

This is pretty simple setting, mixed **Wave Texture** with **Noise** and used as **Bump** for **Glass**.

Before this you have randomization for **Z** position per object to make icicles looks different from each other. They should be separated objects.

### Mesh notes:

It's not part of the question, but I'll try to briefly describe how to use it with this add-on.

To get this working you need to have UV Map for icicles. 
I've used **Cylindrical Projection** on all of them.

After this I've separated icicles - <kbd>P</kbd> > **By loose parts**.

Another issue could be **Smooth Shading**. Check here for solution: [Smooth cone with glossy or anisotropic texture gets dark spot](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?329382-Smooth-cone-with-glossy-or-anisotropic-texture-gets-dark-spot) or use **Flat Shading**.